# Not able to fetch the data from javascript based webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to take out the quarter value present against "Document fiscal period focus" from the link: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=40545&accession_number=0000040545-14-000049&xbrl_type=v#

When i look at the souce of the page it shows below tag for this info:

```
<li class="accordion" id="r1" ><a class="xbrlviewer" onClick="javascript:highlight(this);" href="javascript:loadReport(1);">Document and Entity Information</a></li>
```

In this case, i don't even have to click on anything, this info is there on the webpase but still not shown in the html source.I am sure it has to do something with the javascript in the href.
Please guide me on how to get it done in Python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was generated using javascript. I suggest you use Firebug or Chrome Developer tools to inspect hidden javascript URL calls.

This is the link you're looking for: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/40545/000004054514000049/R1.htm